# global variable not updated pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I wrote this c-program :

```
int counter = 0;

void* increment()
{
  int maxI = 10000;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < maxI; ++i) { counter++; }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread1_id;
  pthread_t thread2_id;
  pthread_create (&thread1_id,NULL,&increment,NULL);
  pthread_create (&thread2_id,NULL,&increment,NULL);
  pthread_join (thread1_id,NULL);
  pthread_join (thread2_id,NULL);
  printf("counter = %d\n",counter);
  return 0;
}
```

As a result I get : `counter = 10000`

why is that ? I would have expected something much bigger instead as I am using two threads, how can I correct it

PS : I am aware that there will be a race condition!

edit : `volatile int counter` seems to solve the problem :)

Comment: You know your code has a bug. Why are you surprised that it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: the code without volatile always outputs 10000, that was my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicting what code with bugs will do is extremely difficult. Most likely, the compiler is optimizing your `increment` function to keep `counter` in a register. But you'd have to look at the generated assembly code to be sure.